# Coordinate Value not displaying after clicking on Map

Tags: coordinate-system, javascript, openlayers

I am trying to create a pop-up using Open Layers which will show the coordinate values when I click on the Map. There are no errors in the console window however, whenever I click on Map it
displays : "You Clicked Here [object object]" and not the actual coordinates of the place where I click. Am attaching the code that I am using.

PS : I am very new to JS so its quite possible I might be missing something very obvious.

**Code Starting**

```
// Creating a View

var view = new ol.View({
    center : [84.2294050294863, 21.330813185563247],
    zoom :5,
    projection : 'EPSG:4326'
}) 

// Elements that make up the popup.

const container = document.getElementById('popup');
const content = document.getElementById('popup-content');
const closer = document.getElementById('popup-closer');

// Add a click handler to hide the popup.

closer.onclick = function () {
  overlay.setPosition(undefined);
  closer.blur();
  return false;
};

// Setting Parameters

var basemap = new ol.layer.Tile({
    source: new ol.source.OSM()
})

var layerArray = [basemap]

//Create an overlay to anchor the popup to the map.

const overlay = new ol.Overlay({
  element: container,
  autoPan: true,
  autoPanAnimation: {
    duration: 250,
  },
});


// Create Map

var map = new ol.Map({
    target : 'map',
    layers : layerArray,
    view : view,
    overlays : [overlay]
});
 

// Add a click handler to the map to render the popup.

map.on('singleclick', function (event) {
    
  const coordinate = event.coordinate;
  const hdms = new ol.coordinate.toStringHDMS(ol.proj.toLonLat(coordinate));

  content.innerHTML = '<p>You clicked here:</p><code>' + hdms + '</code>';
  overlay.setPosition(coordinate);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ol.coordinate.toStringHDMS` is not an object, but just function/method for formatting geographic coordinates, so you don't have to use `new` qualifier when calling/envoking it (see docs at https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_coordinate.html),

It should simply be:

```
const hdms = ol.coordinate.toStringHDMS(ol.proj.toLonLat(coordinate));
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. It really helped.